# "Windows cannot open this file" error for PPTX and XSLX files

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-office-2010

I'm running Windows XP SP3, MS Office 2010 Professional Plus. I'm having trouble with .pptx and .xlsx files.

I know that they're suposed to be associated with MS Powerpoint/Excel 2007+, but for some reason the system (by that I mean Windows Explorer) had completely forgotten the file format; it came up with the following error:

> Windows cannot open this file:
>   File: filename.pptx
>   To open this file, Windows needs to know what program created it...

.docx, .doc, .accdb and .pub are fine. Programs are in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14

I've got full access to Folder Options, so if someone posts the data to put in there I can do the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to repair your Microsoft Office installation first.

You can do this by going into your Control Panel, then to Add/Remove Programs.  Scroll down to Microsoft Office and click once on it, you should see two options, "Change" and "Remove"

If you select Change then you should get the installer pop up and you will have an option to add features or repair Office, the repair option should hopefully repair file associations.